# Calling then function after fetching data from firebase in ionic 3

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I want fetch data from firebase after that I want to execute another function. Second function have to wait until first one is complete .

```
this.oAngularFireDatabase.database.ref('Users').orderByKey()
            .on('value', snapshot => {
              if (snapshot.hasChildren()) {
                snapshot.forEach(innerSnap => {
                  if (innerSnap.hasChild(user.uid)) {
                    //User role key
                    this.loggedInUserUserRoleKey = innerSnap.key;
                    //User id
                    this.loggedInUserId = user.uid;

                    //User name
                    this.loggedInUserName = innerSnap.child(user.uid).child("user_name").val();

                    if (innerSnap.child(user.uid).hasChild("user_image")) {
                      //User Image
                      this.loggedInUserImage = innerSnap.child(user.uid).child("user_image").val();
                    }
                    return false;
                  }
                })
              }
            })
```

I can't call `then` function after `on` it gives me an error. 
In my above code, I want call another function after all data are fetch from firebase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firebase `on()` method can fire multiple times: once when it initially loads the data, and again whenever the data changes. Since a promise (the thing you call `then()` on) can only resolve once, `on()` can't return a promise.

There are two options here:

1. You want to only load the data once.

   If this is the case, you should use Firebase's `once()` method, which *does* return a promise.

   ```
   this.oAngularFireDatabase.database.ref('Users').orderByKey()
       .once('value').then(snapshot => {
         if (snapshot.hasChildren()) {
           snapshot.forEach(innerSnap => {
             if (innerSnap.hasChild(user.uid)) {
               //User role key
               this.loggedInUserUserRoleKey = innerSnap.key;
               //User id
               this.loggedInUserId = user.uid;

               //User name
               this.loggedInUserName = innerSnap.child(user.uid).child("user_name").val();

               if (innerSnap.child(user.uid).hasChild("user_image")) {
                 //User Image
                 this.loggedInUserImage = innerSnap.child(user.uid).child("user_image").val();
               }
               return false;
             }
           })
         }
       }).then(value => {
           // TODO: perform subsequent action on boolean value
       })
   ```
2. You want to listen for changes on the data too.

   If this is the case, you should put the subsequent action you want to take into the `on()` callback:

   ```
   this.oAngularFireDatabase.database.ref('Users').orderByKey()
       .on('value', snapshot => {
         if (snapshot.hasChildren()) {
           snapshot.forEach(innerSnap => {
             if (innerSnap.hasChild(user.uid)) {
               //User role key
               this.loggedInUserUserRoleKey = innerSnap.key;
               //User id
               this.loggedInUserId = user.uid;

               //User name
               this.loggedInUserName = innerSnap.child(user.uid).child("user_name").val();

               if (innerSnap.child(user.uid).hasChild("user_image")) {
                 //User Image
                 this.loggedInUserImage = innerSnap.child(user.uid).child("user_image").val();
               }
             }
           })
           // TODO: perform subsequent action on data
         }
       })
   ```

Note that both of these operations look pretty expensive for what they're trying to accomplish: scanning a JSON tree for a specific value is an anti-pattern in Firebase, and typically means you should modify/augment your JSON to allow a direct lookup or query.

For example, I suspect you now have a structure like `/Users/$randomkey/$uid: { ..user data... }`. For better performance, consider storing the user data directly under their UID: `/Users/$uid: { ..user data... }`. This removes the need for a query, and allows you to directly load the data for a user from `this.oAngularFireDatabase.database.ref('Users').child(user.uid)`.

Comment: you saved my time brother @Frank van Puffelen

Comment: i have structure like **Users/$UserRoleKey/$uid:{}**